# How to divide a range and give it to multiple threads to generate all combinations

Tags: multithreading

I'm creating program, which will generate all possible combinations from given range, with given length.

```
Eg.
range: 1-6
length: 3
111
112
113
114
115
116
121
...
666
```

I can make such program, whoever I want to add multithreading. So I want to receive a number of threads from the user, and divide the work between them, So instand of 1 thread which generate the combinations I want N threads to do it. I can't think of a way to divide the work between the threads. I searched in Google and here, however without any luck probably I'm not using the right keywords. I want some algorithm for this, if you need programming language to describe it to me, I will be able to understand any language from the C family.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possible partition can be by sections (or - prefix) . For example:

range: 1-6, length: 4, N: 2

Thread1: all permutations that start with 1, 2 or 3.

Thread2: all permutations that start with 4, 5 or 6.

Since you already know how to output all permutations with one thread, just create N threads, but give them a new length (in the above example - new_length = 3). This should be easy enough if you have a single-threaded working code. Now, for each thread, just add all the prefixes of the thread. Back to the example - after Thread1 is done creating all permutations of {range: 1-6, **length: 3**}, you just create 3 permutations from each value of the results - one with prefix of "1", one with prefix of 2, and one with prefix of "3". for 556, for example, you output 1556, 2556, 3556.

Comment: I want to as what if the thread count is larger than the characters in the range(N: 12 for example), Can I use all threads to do work?

Comment: I guess you can recursively split the load between them. In my example, if you want 10 threads instead of 2, then split the load of thread1 to 5 threads, in exactly the same way.